# Как обрабатывать paintComponent на GPU?

Tags: java, swing, gpu

Я сделал отрисовку белого шума в paintComponent, но я получил 10 fps, т.к. обрабатывалось это всё на CPU. Есть ли какой-то простой способ использовать всю мощь GPU? Я пробовал Aparapi, но мне говорили, что что-то не поддерживает новые инструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");`